# Microsoft Excel Exercises for learning purposes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm not sure if it belongs this here, but if you feel it doesn't just please remove it. I'm looking for a good source of exercises in excel that is good in teaching a friend of mine that wants to learn excel. I want the exercises to be similar in the school/university. I will just have to spend some time teaching him.

Answer (score 2):

The following link is dedicated to teaching people how to use Excel in whatever mode they want to learn in. (intermediate, expert, etc) http://www.abacustraining.biz/ExcelExercises.htm

Comment: awesome find man! :) it would really be a big helps for me.